# Excel: Formula to Create a list of Highest values with the corresponding text cell beside the value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel spreadsheet that has two columns

Column A shows the names of a particular category and is repeated Column B counts the amount of times the category is listed.

I would just like to compile a list that only shows the category and the maximum recorded number beside the category.

Example

```
Agricultural Services  1    
Agricultural Services  2    
Agricultural Services  3    
Bakeries               1    
Bakeries               2    
Bakeries               3
```

I would like to create a separate list that only shows

```
Agricultural Services   3    
Bakeries                3
```

Comment: Use a Pivot Table.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good explanation of how to list/count *unique* and *distinct* values [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/04/21/get-list-unique-values-excel/).

Below is a table containing your example data and the extra columns to list and count the distinct values.

[image]

To get this result, enter this formula in C2 and fill down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$7),0,0),0)),"")
```

And this formula in D2 and fill down:

```
 =IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$7,C2)<>0,COUNTIF(A$2:A$7,C2),"")
```

Comment: @Chad S, if you found this helpful, please see [this help page](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)